Iron Pdf are not loading fonts
I'm using Iron Pdf, but there is a problem when using external fonts using imports through @font-face.
Even setting a delay on firstrender, in production it returns a blank PDF.
Would anyone have an alternative to resolve it?
Below is an example of the code that is rendering the HTML/CSS:
  try
  {
      _logger.Debug(LogContext, "start chrome render", options);
      var renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer
      {
          RenderingOptions = CreateRenderOptionsFrom(options)
      };

      if (_isFirstRender)
      {
          _logger.Debug(LogContext, "first render");
          //We need to add a delay in the render process because we are using external fonts on the template, 
          //after the first render, this does not look like a issue anymore. Link below for refence
          //https://ironpdf.com/examples/google-fonts-htmltopdf/
          _isFirstRender = false;
          #if DEBUG
          renderer.RenderingOptions.RenderDelay = 500;
          #else
          renderer.RenderingOptions.RenderDelay = 1200;
          #endif
      }

      var (first, rest) = pages;
      _logger.Debug(LogContext, "creating first page");
      var pdf = await renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(first);
      _logger.Debug(LogContext, "created first page");
      foreach (var page in rest)
      {
          _logger.Debug(LogContext, "creating next page");
          var newPage = await renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(page);
          pdf.AppendPdf(newPage);
          _logger.Debug(LogContext, "created next page");
      }

      _logger.Debug(LogContext, "reading stream");

      using var ms = pdf.Stream;
      var buffer = await ms.GetBufferAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
      var file = FileRaw.Create(buffer, ExtensionMap.pdf);

      _logger.Debug(LogContext, "readed stream");
      return file.AsRight<Exception, FileRaw>();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      return ex.AsLeft<Exception, FileRaw>();
  }

I tried setting a render timer, for the first render, for loading the fonts, and before rendering the PDF, but it doesn't work well on my local host.
I also tried to follow some steps in the documents, like this https://ironpdf.com/how-to/manage-fonts/
but we can't update to the latest due to incompatibility with another lib

Could you share how you are using the @font-face to import the font file?
Try to set a higher RenderDelay(10000 ms) just to be sure. Could you provide the log file that is generated by IronPdf as well?
For this issue only, you do not need to be on the latest. I do not recall a bug related to font in the previous versions. Please reach out to support@ironsoftware.com so that I can keep track of the issue.

Hey @ChaknithBin, I was working on this problem and the solutions were to update the version or bring the fonts to my server, I chose to bring the fonts to my server and use the delay during the pdf loading.
Tks for help!
